# Tabulator Table on ReactJS - How to get the selectedData

Tags: reactjs, tabulator

Hi Im using Tabulator on our React Project and I'm trying to get the selected data on click button.
Here is my code:

```
const SkusTable = ({ data }) => {
  const [selectedData, setSelectedData] = useState()

  let tableRef = useRef()
  let table

  const tabulatorOptions = {
    reactiveData: true,
    data,
    // height: "100vh",
    layout: "fitData",
    // dataTree: true,
    dataTreeStartExpanded: true,
    progressiveLoad: "scroll",
    paginationSize: 20,
    // selectable: true,
    columns: SkusTableColumns,
    dataTreeChildField: "_children",
    rowFormatter: (row) => {
      //create and style holder elements
      const holderEl = document.createElement("div")
      const tableEl = document.createElement("div")

      holderEl.style.padding = "10px 30px 10px 10px"
      holderEl.appendChild(tableEl)

      row.getElement().appendChild(holderEl)

      if (row._row.data._children?.length > 0) {
        const subTable = new Tabulator(tableEl, {
          // new Tabulator(tableEl, {
          layout: "fitColumns",
          dataTreeChildField: "_children",
          selectable: true,
          data: row.getData()._children,
          columns: SubColumns
        })
        console.log({ subTable })
      }
    }
  }

  const initTable = (tableRef, tabulatorOptions) => {
    const table = new Tabulator(tableRef, tabulatorOptions)
    return table
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    table = initTable(tableRef, tabulatorOptions)
  }, [data, selectedData])

  const clickHandler = () => {
    setSelectedData(table.getSelectedData())
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ selectedData, table, tableRef })
  }, [selectedData, table])

  return (
    <>
      <Button className="ms-2 mb-2" color="primary" onClick={clickHandler}>
        Get Data
      </Button>
      <h2>Number: {selectedData?.length}</h2>
      <div ref={(el) => (tableRef = el)} />
    </>
  )
}

export default SkusTable
```

When clicking the Get Data Button, it returns an error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getSelectedData')

When I clicked the button and console.log the table, it returns undefined

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: don't use `table` variable instead create a state for it using `useState` and set the table data in first `useEffect` where you are using `initTable`.

Comment: Try make table varitable be a ref too.

Comment: I did try useState and it work. Thank you @ShubhamWaje. You are awesome
However, after clicking the button. the selection disappears then when I clicked the rows again it return this error:

```react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Event Target Lookup Error - The row this cell is attached to cannot be found, has the table been reinitialized without being destroyed first?```

do you know what does this means and how to solve it
Thank you

Comment: I think `selectedData` in the dependency array of the first `useEffect` is causing this error. So, the issue is stating that you have already initialised the table using `initTable` on the first mount but when you are clicking the button and updating the `selectedData` state, the `useEffect` with `initTable` is getting executed again and the table is getting reinitialised. So I believe remove `selectedData` from the dependency array of that `useEffect` as you have to initialise the table once. :)

Comment: Hi @LiHS, thank you for your answer. When I use `useRef` on table, it returns `current:undefined`
How can I apply it to the code?
Thank you

Comment: @ShubhamWaje you are right, by removing the `selectedData` in the dependancy of the first `useEffect`, it removes the desselection. 
But the error is still there regarding 
`react_devtools_backend.js:4012 Event Target Lookup Error - The row this cell is attached to cannot be found, has the table been reinitialized without being destroyed first?`

Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @lester23 Do you use `table.current = initTable...`? It will be better, if you can provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) link of your code.

Comment: Where is this `new Tabulator` and all coming from? Are you using any kind of library for it?

Comment: @ShubhamWaje Yes it's a library. 
Here is the docs:
[Tabulator.info](https://tabulator.info/)

Here is the code in sandbox:
[table](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-meninsky-hu64bz?file=/src/App.js)

Thanks a lot

Comment: [React usage for tabular](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/blob/master/src/ReactTabulator.tsx) Here is something that I found which you should follow while using this library with react. Please refer this. :)

Comment: your always welcome :-P